# Knn in R error "dims of 'test' and 'train' differ"

Tags: r

I have the code below and error at the end is "dims of 'test' and 'train' differ". I don't understand why I am getting this error.

```
library(readxl)
library(ISLR)
library(class)

winered$quality02 = 0
winered$quality02[winered$quality > median(winered$quality)] = 1

summary(as.factor(winered$quality02))

split <- sort(sample(nrow(winered), nrow(winered)*.7))
winered.train <- winered[split,]
winered.test <- winered[-split,]

mis.rates = function(x,y) sum(x!=y)/length(x)

knn.k = seq(2, 10, by = 1)

k.cv.knn.error = matrix(0,length(knn.k))

k = 0
for (K in knn.k){
  k=k+1
  knn.pred.test = knn(winered.train$quality02, winered.test[$quality02, cl=as.factor(winered.train$quality02), k=K)
  k.cv.knn.error[k] = mis.rates(knn.pred.test, winered.test$quality02)
}
```

Comment: Where can we find the data set `winered`?

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in the line that begins `knn.pred.test = ...`. There is a misplaced opening bracket in `winered.test[$quality2`

Comment: @RuiBarradas     https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/red-wine-quality-cortez-et-al-2009

Comment: @jdobres  I corrected that but still giving error                                https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/red-wine-quality-cortez-et-al-2009

Answer (score 0):

The data set in the link is in a sub-directory `data` of the working directory. The code below first reads the data, then splits it, then fits the KNN models. No errors are given after correcting the arguments to function `knn`. This function accepts as `train` and `test` arguments matrices or data.frames, not vectors like the code in the question is passing to it.

```
library(readr)
library(class)

# Import the datasets.
# 'red' is the red wine dataset
# 'white' is the white wine dataset.
col_spec <- cols(
  `fixed acidity` = col_double(),
  `volatile acidity` = col_double(),
  `citric acid` = col_double(),
  `residual sugar` = col_double(),
  chlorides = col_double(),
  `free sulfur dioxide` = col_double(),
  `total sulfur dioxide` = col_double(),
  density = col_double(),
  pH = col_double(),
  sulphates = col_double(),
  alcohol = col_double(),
  quality = col_double()
)

winered   <- read_delim("data/winequality-red.csv", 
                    delim = ";", 
                    locale = locale(decimal_mark = ".", 
                                    grouping_mark = ","), 
                    col_types = col_spec,
                    col_names = TRUE)

winered$quality02 <- 0
winered$quality02[winered$quality > median(winered$quality)] <- 1
winered$quality02 <- factor(winered$quality02)
summary(winered$quality02)

set.seed(2021)
split <- sample(nrow(winered), nrow(winered) * 0.7)
winered.train <- winered[split,]
winered.test <- winered[-split,]

mis.rates <- function(x, y) sum(x != y)/length(x)

knn.k <- 2:10

k.cv.knn.error <- numeric(length(knn.k))

for (K in knn.k){
  knn.pred.test <- knn(train = winered.train["quality02"], 
                      test = winered.test["quality02"], 
                      cl = winered.train$quality02, 
                      k = K)


  k.cv.knn.error[K - 1L] <- mis.rates(knn.pred.test, winered.test$quality02)
}
```